# Is there a Firefox plug in which can list unsecure assets which are causing the "Warning: Contains unauthenticated content"

Tags: firefox, https, http-headers, security

I am developing web pages which reference external links/images/stylesheets etc. I have 1 page which loads fine in HTTPS, but then when I apply different external styles, some of the external styles cause a warning "Contains unauthenticated content"

Don't get me wrong, I understand *WHAT* this means, but I can't see any reference to any HTTP requests in View source, Firebug, Live HTTP Headers or in the View Page Info > Media window.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas of plug ins or tools which can identify exactly which items Firefox is not happy with?

Unfortunately this page is not live on the internet so I can't show it to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Proxomitron](http://www.proxomitron.info/) and this showed the file!

Comment: Although the program blinded me with its colors, it helped me locate the problem. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could, theoretically, use a proxy that just logs all requests and redirects them to the server. Of course, that is a *very* roundabout way of doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use FireFox to see the media assets. Click on the lock on the Status Bar when you are on a secure page, then Media.